# Accessing a new install of Windows 2003 Server R2 from the network

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, firewall, windows-server-2003-r2

I have installed Windows 2003 Server R2 on a machine from scratch and by default, Windows 2003 Server is locked down, but now I need to open access to it from my corporate network.

From the server, I can access other servers on the network, I can also access the internet.

What do I need to do, in order to gain access to shares on this server, etc?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you finish up the R2 updating wizard?  The one that says at the end that it will open up the computer for other connections?

Comment: I think so - but possibly not.  Can I kick-start that again?

Comment: It should keep coming up until you complete it, so it sounds like you have.  The server is joined to a Windows domain?

Comment: It is already joined to the domain, yes.  I've been installing updates on it all day, and have been rebooting accordingly but haven't seen any pop-up about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your firewall is enabled make sure you allow the exceptions for 'File and Print' and 'Remote Desktop'. That will allow you to get to the shares.

I'm guessing you can't ping the server from your workstation? Enabling 'File and Print' will enable ICMP so you can ping the server as well.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no firewall as yet... Windows 2003 Server doesn't have the same built in firewall as 2008 Server, does it?

Comment: Ah... yes it does... my bad.

Comment: So was your firewall enabled? Do you have a resolution?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have shared the Window 2003 installation files.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't finish the configuration procedure so the firewall is configured to block everything. Start windows firewall and add exceptions for each role the machine needs to fulfill or turn off windows firewall.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of error do you get?

Any kind of useful info if you do

start ---> eventvwr

Comment: When I try to access the server from another server or workstation, I get a response as though the server is not there. Same too if I try to use Remote Desktop Connection to it also.